# Proof that $a^x$ goes towards infinity as x goes towards infinity

Tags: proof-writing, exponential-function

I'm tasked to prove that $a^x \rightarrow \infty $ when $x \rightarrow \infty$ provided that (a > 1).

I've found a very rigorous proof for this. But my question is, why can't it be logically realized that "$a$ times $a$ an infinite amount of times produces an infinite product"?

Comment: First things first, $x$ is (presumably) a real number. Second, what does it mean to multiply something an infinite number of times?

Comment: When you say something goes to $\infty$, that has a very precise definition.  Just because it's feels intuitive doesn't mean it shouldn't be proven.

Answer (score 1):

If $x\in\mathbb{R}$ then

$$\forall \,N>0\,\,\exists \,M>0\,\,:\,\,\,x>M\,\,\Rightarrow \,\,a^x>N$$
because we can assume $x>\log_{a}N$. Indeed we choose $M$ such that $M>\log_{a}N$